# between dates columns in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a problem about a query.I want to list all dates according to given date  between currentDate and finishDate.In other words, if given date is between startDate and finishDate, I want to list rows.  The currentDate and finishDate are column names on the table. Types are Long now.Example dates are 2011,2015 etc.

```
    @Query("select u from Players u where u.year = BETWEEN startDate and  finishDate)
     List<Dates> findAllDatesBetweenStarAndEnd(@Param("year") Long year);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be corrected as below:

```
select u from Players u where u.year BETWEEN :startDate AND :finishDate
```